# Convert R2 to Cohen's d

Tags: r

I am looking to convert the output of the lm function to Cohen's d, so far I have been able to extract the r2, however, how can I retrieve Cohen's d from R2 in r?

```
m <- lm(outcome ~ predictor, data = df)
summary(m)$adj.r.squared
```

Also any idea how to calculate the upper and lower bounds of the r2?

Answer (score 2):

The [lsr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsr/lsr.pdf) package seems to provide a function for calculating Cohen's d:

```
cohensD(outcome ~ predictor, data = df)
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the upper and lower bounds of the r2 you can bootstrap. Function `boot::boot` is very easy to use, if you choose to use this method.

**Data**

```
set.seed(1072)   # Make it reproducible

predictor <- rnorm(100)
outcome <- predictor + rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(predictor, outcome)
```

**Code**

```
bootfun <- function(DF, index){
    m <- lm(outcome ~ predictor, data = DF[index, ])
    summary(m)$adj.r.squared
}

b <- boot::boot(df, bootfun, R = 1000)
quantile(b$t, c(0.025, 0.975))
     2.5%     97.5% 
0.4065505 0.6500718
```

Comment: Wow that's a nice solution